# Local Database development in cross platform applications windows phone 7 in particular. (develop using javascript)

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, cross-platform, local-storage, local-database

I am developing an application for Windows phone 7 which uses offline database. I have seen some of the solutions for this as follows Sqlite DB http://sqlitewindowsphone.codeplex.com/ Mango DB http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2011/06/windows-phone-7-mango-tutorial-24-local.html

My Question is All these databases are using Native code i.e development in C#. But i would like to develop local database either phonegap or javascript or else any other which uses for cross platform applications (windows phone in particular). Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please suggest is there any local database for windows phone 7 application.

Answer (score 1):

You should check Web SQL, here are some resources:

- [Phonegap Storage documentation, including working code](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html)
- [Web SQL Database tutorial](http://marakana.com/s/post/208/tutorial_web_sql_database)

Also, consider integrating SQLite:

- [Related question from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987238/sqlite-database-on-phonegap-ios-more-than-5mb-possible)
- [Working example using SQLite](https://gist.github.com/edwardtoday/2204864)

Good luck, I hope this helped.

Comment: PhoneGap storage doesn't support windows-phone-7 according to their own documentation